# How to use lambda expression when defining index filter or check constraint in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have an entity that looks something like this

```cs
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DeploymentStateType State { get; set; }
}

public enum DeploymentStateType
{
    Unknown,
    InDeployment,
    DeploymentComplete
}
```

In my model builder, I want to define a filtered index on `ApplicationId` where `State == InDeployment`.

Seemingly, the fluent API only allows a hardcoded SQL fragment via this syntax:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationConfiguration>()
    .HasIndex(ac => ac.ApplicationId)
    .HasFilter("State == 1");
```

Now this is obviously fragile for two reasons:

- No intellisense/refactoring support for the column name ("State") in the filter expression
- Reference to enum "magic number"

The way I'm solving the problem is:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationConfiguration>()
    .HasIndex(ac => ac.ApplicationId)
    .HasFilter($"{nameof(ApplicationConfiguration.State)} == {(int)DeploymentStateType.InDeployment}");
```

But this is obviously ugly and unwieldy.

In an ideal world, I would be able to do specify it using a lambda:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationConfiguration>()
    .HasIndex(ac => ac.ApplicationId)
    .HasFilter(ac => ac.State == DeploymentStateType.InDeployment);
```

However, `HasFilter()` does not seem to have an overload that accepts a lambda. (As of writing, I'm using EF Core 6.0.5 which seems to be the latest stable release.)

This should theoretically be possible, because:

- `Where()` knows how to do it
- model builder knows it's building a model from SQL Server dialect, so already at this stage know how to generate correct SQL

This problem pertains to `HasCheckConstraint()` as well, which also only seems to accept a raw SQL string.

***Q:*** Is there a way to have EF generate the SQL fragment for me, having the filter lambda as an input?

Comment: Not much into EF, but looks like `HasFilter` has an [interesting overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalindexbuilderextensions.hasfilter?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationalindexbuilderextensions-hasfilter-1(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-indexbuilder((-0))-system-string))

Comment: Your filter is pretty simplistic and could easily be handled with expression trees.  That said, filters can be a lot less trivial than that, which might be why what you're after is not supported out of the box.  You could, however, create your own extension method with whatever syntax you like and generate the SQL yourself (as you've noted, it's not too hard to generate).

Comment: I think, main reason why Lambda syntax is not supported, because here entity is not configured yet. So EF do not know how to map properties. For sure they can do that later, exactly before migration, but probably it can be difficult also.